# make native for minikube deploy give me java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.settings.Mirror.isBlocked()Z

Tags: docker, native, java-11, quarkus, minikube

i try minikube on VirtualBox with quarkus java frmework ( set quarkus.kubernetes.image-pull-policy=Never)  but when i try to prepare for build a native executable, adding jib extension on quarkus, on maven with command

```
quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions=kubernetes,jib -X
```

(Oracle 11 jdk )
I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:add-extension failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:add-extension: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.settings.Mirror.isBlocked()Z
```

Why?

My pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>account-service</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.2.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for kubernetes  automatic configs generation in targeet/kubernetes-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-kubernetes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for minikube automatic configs generation in targeet/kubernetes-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-minikube</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-container-image-jib -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-jib</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <to>
            <image>myimage</image>
          </to>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

I try to watch this guide but without pushing image on public docker hub:
https://dev.to/marcuspaulo/tutorial-publish-a-quarkus-application-in-kubernetes-minikube-and-dockerhub-36nd

What's the problem?
Thanks!
My application is:

```
    quarkus.container-image.group=quarkus-mp
    quarkus.container-image.name=account-service
    quarkus.kubernetes.name=account-service
    quarkus.kubernetes.image-pull-policy=Never

The maven log is :




  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Progetti\altri\account-service -Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=50989:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2021.1.3 quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions=kubernetes,jib -X
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
    Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
    Maven home: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
    Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
    Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
    [DEBUG]   Included C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 
...
    [DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.quarkus.registry:quarkus-platforms:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Progetti\.m2\repository)
    [DEBUG] Failure to find io.quarkus.registry:quarkus-platforms:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in http://nexus.xxx.it/repository/dev was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of public has elapsed or updates are forced
    [DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.quarkus.registry:quarkus-platforms:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Progetti\.m2\repository)
    [DEBUG] Resolving non-platform extension catalog io.quarkus.registry:quarkus-non-platform-extensions:json:2.2.1.Final:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.quarkus.registry:quarkus-non-platform-extensions:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Progetti\.m2\repository)
    [DEBUG] Failure to find io.quarkus.registry:quarkus-non-platform-extensions:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in http://nexus.xxx.it/repository/dev was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of public has elapsed or updates are forced
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  8.078 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-05T14:38:46+02:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:add-extension (default-cli) on project account-service: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:add-extension failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:add-extension: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.settings.Mirror.isBlocked()Z
```

kuberntes.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2021-09-05 - 12:23:51 +0000
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: account-service
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  name: account-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: account-service
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2021-09-05 - 12:23:51 +0000
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    app.kubernetes.io/name: account-service
  name: account-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
      app.kubernetes.io/name: account-service
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2021-09-05 - 12:23:51 +0000
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        app.kubernetes.io/name: account-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          image: quarkus-mp/account-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          name: account-service
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Can you try with Maven 3.8.1 please?

Comment: i have tried and the error now is "[ERROR] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": CreateProcess error=2, Impossibile trovare il file specificato" i thing we can speak in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070895/error-deploying-quarkus-rest-app-from-my-windows-machine-to-my-minikube-virtual?noredirect=1#comment122078566_69070895