# error deploying quarkus rest app from my windows machine to my minikube (virtual box machine)

Tags: kubernetes, java-11, quarkus, minikube

I get thi error when i try to deploy on Minikube. I have minikube in VirtualkBox and i exec commands like in this guide: https://www.kubernetesbyexample.com/en/learning-paths/developing-quarkus-kubernetes/getting-started-quarkus/running-kubernetes

My problem arises when i put the command:
mvn clean package -Dquarkus.kubernetes.deploy=true

Before, i have run $(minikube docker-env) in windows like this:

```
C:\Users\xxx>minikube docker-env
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\xxx\.minikube\certs
SET MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD=minikube
REM To point your shell to minikube's docker-daemon, run:
REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env') DO @%i

C:\Users\xxx>@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env') DO @%i
```

but issue still remain, this is maven log and stacktrace:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Progetti\altri\account-service -Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=58328:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2021.1.3 clean package -Dquarkus.kubernetes.deploy=true
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< quarkus:account-service >-----------------------
[INFO] Building account-service 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ account-service ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Progetti\altri\account-service\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:generate-code (default) @ account-service ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ account-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ account-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Progetti\altri\account-service\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:generate-code-tests (default) @ account-service ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ account-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Progetti\altri\account-service\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ account-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Progetti\altri\account-service\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ account-service ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running quarkus.GreetingResourceTest
2021-09-06 09:27:56,109 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 2.2.1.Final on JVM started in 12.208s. Listening on: http://localhost:8081
2021-09-06 09:27:56,115 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated. 
2021-09-06 09:27:56,115 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, kubernetes, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 35.312 s - in quarkus.GreetingResourceTest
2021-09-06 09:28:01,726 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus stopped in 0.141s
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ account-service ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Progetti\altri\account-service\target\account-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:build (default) @ account-service ---
[INFO] [org.jboss.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.4.2.Final
[INFO] [io.quarkus.kubernetes.deployment.KubernetesDeployer] Selecting target 'minikube' since it has the highest priority among the implicitly enabled deployment targets
[INFO] Checking for existing resources in: C:\Progetti\altri\account-service\src\main\kubernetes.
[INFO] [io.quarkus.kubernetes.deployment.KubernetesDeploy] Kubernetes API Server at 'https://192.168.99.100:8443/' successfully contacted.
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] Starting container image build
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] Base image 'fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk11-jre' does not use a specific image digest - build may not be reproducible
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] The base image requires auth. Trying again for fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk11-jre...
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] Using base image with digest: sha256:b459cc59d6c7ddc9fd52f981fc4c187f44a401f2433a1b4110810d2dd9e98a07
[INFO] [io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor] Container entrypoint set to [java, -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager, -jar, quarkus-run.jar]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:25 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-06T09:28:19+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:build (default) on project account-service: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor#buildFromJar threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create container image
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor.containerize(JibProcessor.java:194)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor.buildFromJar(JibProcessor.java:134)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:820)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": CreateProcess error=2, Impossibile trovare il file specificato
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:566)
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:547)
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:88)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.StepsRunner.run(StepsRunner.java:219)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.api.Containerizer.run(Containerizer.java:366)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.api.JibContainerBuilder.containerize(JibContainerBuilder.java:598)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor.containerize(JibProcessor.java:187)
[ERROR]     ... 12 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": CreateProcess error=2, Impossibile trovare il file specificato
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.docker.DockerClient.docker(DockerClient.java:277)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.docker.DockerClient.load(DockerClient.java:193)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.LoadDockerStep.call(LoadDockerStep.java:74)
[ERROR]     at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.StepsRunner.lambda$loadDocker$18(StepsRunner.java:618)
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
[ERROR]     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Impossibile trovare il file specificato
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:420)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:151)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
[ERROR]     ... 11 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

This is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>account-service</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.2.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for kubernetes  automatic configs generation in targeet/kubernetes-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-kubernetes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for minikube automatic configs generation in targeet/kubernetes-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-minikube</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-container-image-jib -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-jib</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <from>
            <image></image>
          </from>
          <to>
            <image>myimage</image>
          </to>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

and minikube yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2021-09-06 - 07:28:08 +0000
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: account-service
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  name: account-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      nodePort: 30704
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: account-service
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2021-09-06 - 07:28:08 +0000
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: account-service
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  name: account-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: account-service
      app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        app.quarkus.io/build-timestamp: 2021-09-06 - 07:28:08 +0000
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: account-service
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          image: quarkus-mp/account-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: account-service
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
```

My application (using policy never no docker hub public image) :

```
quarkus.container-image.group=quarkus-mp
quarkus.container-image.name=account-service
quarkus.kubernetes.name=account-service
quarkus.kubernetes.image-pull-policy=Never
quarkus.kubernetes.service-type=NodePort
```

What's the problem?

Thank you very much!

Roby

Comment: Which Kubernetes version did you use? Do you have installed docker?

Comment: Do you have `docker` on your `$PATH`?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak : * minikube v1.22.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.18363 Build 18363

Comment: @geoand docker is internal to minikube and docker reside in the OS installed in the virtual box (is a Virtual Machine) , i have docker on PATH but not in the windows machine that's the place where a packaging my quarkus application.  the OS in Virtual box is Linux 4.19.182 x86_84 Buildroot 2020.02.12

Comment: i update to maven 3.8.1 but the issue still remain..

Comment: I just ran into this problem on MacOS 10.15.7 and minikube 1.22.0. After re-creating the minikube image minikube delete, minikube start) and it still failing, I just rebooted the Mac as a hail-mary quick-fix attempt. It worked. Maybe network-related. Next time I'll try to debug in a more proper way.

Comment: @JohnClingan i do minikube delete and then restart (recreating VM), set all paths of minuke-env in environments vartables, and i also try with maven wrapper (mvn 3.8.1) but the same issue persist.. can we do the same thing with kubectl -f apply kubernetes.yaml? Thanks